# Scala : access/edit a Map from dataframe.foreach

Tags: scala, apache-spark, foreach, accumulator

I am fairly new to scala so any tips/basics are most welcome. I am trying to access and edit a mutable map from within a dataframe.foreach but I am unable to do that.

Now I understand how spark executes on multiple executors and data is replicated onto each node for computation. So i searched online and got the **collectionAccumulator** class that would help in persisting a collection across nodes.

My code

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.{Calendar, Date}
import org.joda.time.DateTime

import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Row} 
import spark.sparkContext._

import org.apache.spark.{AccumulableParam, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializer
import scala.collection.mutable.{ HashMap => MutableHashMap }


var m  =  scala.collection.mutable.Map("AL" -> "Alabama")


// this creates a collection(list) of accumulator 
var mutableMapAcc= spark.sparkContext.collectionAccumulator[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,String]]("mutableMap") 
mutableMapAcc.add(  scala.collection.mutable.Map("defaultKey" -> "defaultValue"))

var _mutableMap = scala.collection.mutable.Map("mmap" -> "mmapvalue")

val df = Seq(
          ("Andy","a1", 20,new DateTime().toString()),     
          ("Berta","b1", 30,new DateTime().toString()),
          ("Joe","j1", 40,new DateTime().toString())).toDF("name","sector","age","AsOfDate")


println("===================================before foreach======================================================")
println(mutableMapAcc)
println("=========================================================================================")
df.foreach { row =>
 println(mutableMapAcc.value.size)
 mutableMapAcc.add(scala.collection.mutable.Map( row(0).toString() -> row(1).toString() ) )
 println(mutableMapAcc.value) 
}
println("===================================after foreach======================================================")
println(mutableMapAcc)
```

Output :

[image]

Everytime I an getting the size of the mutableMapAcc as zero. I want to access the first map that I added in the statement(below)

```
mutableMapAcc.add(  scala.collection.mutable.Map("defaultKey" -> "defaultValue"))
```

from the foreach loop and then make it behave like a Dictionary (like we do it in C#) and add to the dictionary like :

```
mutableMapAcc.value.get(0) += row(0).toString() -> row(1).toString()
```

Also, I know that such data structures have to be lightweight as broadcast to all the nodes would happen every time there are reads and writes to the map (in my case) and that is okay for my use case. **I just want to avoid the introduction of another service for this (like redis/ any db) if spark can do it for me.**

Comment: An accumulator is not for sharing data. As far as I know, an accumulator is like an *empty* bucket each task get from the driver at the beginning of their execution so they can throw stuff to it. After each task finishes, they hand back the bucket to the driver, where they are dumped together.

Comment: Ohk.  So any other higher level spark api to achieve what I intend to do here?

Comment: Not really. Probably you need to split your program in two.